# why it is giving output as 'bye'? please discuss

Tags: c, if-statement, sizeof

Please give the reason for the output...why it's giving 'bye' while the condition if statement is true because the size of int is 2 or 4 byte.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
        #include<conio.h>
        int main()
        {
        if(sizeof(int)>-1)
            printf("hi");
        else
            printf("bye");
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Check the type of `sizeof()`.

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof

> Both versions return a value of type size_t.

See size_t, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t
which states that it is unsigned.

If therefor the comparison is effectively with a high positive value,
then the logical expression is basically always false.

If you would help the compiler understand what you really want to do,
e.g. by changing to

```
((int)sizeof(int))>-1
```

things are different.

Comment: @M.M. How blind can I be? I looked explicitly - and blindly. Yes you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the return type of `sizeof()` is `size_t` and `sizeof()` never gives size in negative bytes.

`sizeof(int)` results is type of `unsigned`.

And here 
`if(sizeof(int)>-1)`
Comparison is happening between different types i.e `signed(-1)` and `unsigned`. So internally compiler will do **implicit typecasting i.e signed gets converted into unsigned** and **-1** equivalent unsigned value is all one's i.e `4294967295`.

So now condition looks like
`if(4 > 4294967295)`
Which is false so it prints `bye`.

See this for `sizeof()` return type  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t